# my SKLearn based Multi-Model endpoint cannot read my data

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have successfully trained and deployed an SKLearn Logistic Regression based multi-model endpoint. it trained with no issue, and both endpoints are accessible. but when I send it my text data I get the following error:

An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from primary with message "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'". See

this is particularly frustrating, because no-where in my script or in my code I am attempting to use .lower() on my numpy array. I can only assume that despite me using a numpy serializer that it is still expecting the numpy array data to have the .lower() function. It's doubly frustrating that it seems that I cannot use one of the few data formats that sklearn models can readily digest.   Everything else is being done within the notebook environment.

the first model works perfectly fine as a single model endpoint, however once I scaled it up to accommodate more models all of a sudden the same exact inputs that worked previously now no longer work at all. Here is the code I have been using:

cell-1 trainer

```
def launch_training_job(name):
    
    model_name = name.replace(' ', '')
    
    # put the path in here
    if(name == "triage"):
        path_name = 'train'
    else:
        path_name = 'train_' + name.lower().replace(' ', '_')
    
    # set up s3 prefixes and uri's
    s3_prefix = "script-mode-workflow"
    pickle_s3_prefix = f"{s3_prefix}/pickle"
    pickle_s3_uri = f"s3://{bucket}/{s3_prefix}/pickle"
    pickle_train_s3_uri = f"{pickle_s3_uri}/{path_name}"
    
    # create directory
    train_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "")
    
    # upload data
    s3_resource_bucket = boto3.Session().resource("s3").Bucket(bucket)
    s3_resource_bucket.Object(os.path.join(pickle_s3_prefix, path_name + ".pickle")).upload_file(
        train_dir + "/" + path_name + ".pickle"
    )
    
    full_output_prefix = f"{s3_prefix}/model_artifacts/{model_name}"
    s3_output_path = f"s3://{bucket}/{full_output_prefix}"

    # set hyper parameters (not actually used but need to exist)
    hyperparameters = {
        "copy_X": True,
        "fit_intercept": True,
        "normalize": False,
    }
    
    train_instance_type = "ml.m5.large"

    # set the estimator parameters
    estimator_parameters = {
        "entry_point": "script2.py",
        "source_dir": "script",
        "output_path" : s3_output_path,
        "framework_version": "1.0-1",
        "py_version": "py3",
        "instance_type": train_instance_type,
        "instance_count": 1,
        "hyperparameters": hyperparameters,
        "role": role,
        "base_job_name": model_name,
    }
    
    model = SKLearn(**estimator_parameters)

    # I don't know if I need to set up distribution yet or if it's just a suggestion
    
    inputs = {
        "train": pickle_train_s3_uri
    }
    
    model.fit(inputs, wait=False)

    # Return the estimator object
    return model
```

cell-2 job launcher

```
import shutil
import os

estimators = []
# estimator = launch_training_job(loc)

shutil.rmtree("data", ignore_errors=True)


# run two training jobs
estimator = launch_training_job('triage')
estimators.append(estimator)

estimator = launch_training_job(DataSets[0]['group'])
estimators.append(estimator)

# I only wanted to test two models here but I could introduce a loop to train even more


print()
print(
    f"{len(estimators)} training jobs launched: {[x.latest_training_job.job_name for x in estimators]}"
)
```

> > > 2 training jobs launched: ['triage-2023-05-17-01-17-51-276', 'ActiveDirectory-2023-05-17-01-17-52-435']

cell-3

```
from sagemaker.multidatamodel import MultiDataModel
from time import gmtime, strftime

estimator = estimators[0]
model = estimator.create_model(role=role)

ENDPOINT_NAME = f'mme-incident-triage-{strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())}'
MODEL_NAME = ENDPOINT_NAME

mme = MultiDataModel(
    name=MODEL_NAME,
    model_data_prefix=model_data_prefix,
    model=model,  # passing our model - passes container image needed for the endpoint
    sagemaker_session=sess,
)

ENDPOINT_INSTANCE_TYPE = "ml.m5.large"

predictor = mme.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, 
    instance_type=ENDPOINT_INSTANCE_TYPE, 
    endpoint_name=ENDPOINT_NAME
)
```

> > > INFO:sagemaker:Creating model with name: mme-incident-triage-2023-05-17-01-49-21
> > > INFO:sagemaker:Creating endpoint-config with name mme-incident-triage-2023-05-17-01-49-21
> > > INFO:sagemaker:Creating endpoint with name mme-incident-triage-2023-05-17-01-49-21
> > > ----!

cell-4

```
for est in estimators:
    artifact_path = est.latest_training_job.describe()["ModelArtifacts"]["S3ModelArtifacts"]
    model_name = artifact_path.split("/")[-4] + ".tar.gz"
    # This is copying over the model artifact to the S3 location for the MME.
    mme.add_model(model_data_source=artifact_path, model_data_path=model_name)
```

cell-5

```
type(DataSets[0]['x_test'])
```

> > > pandas.core.series.Series

cell-6 "the problem cell"

```
from sagemaker.serializers import NumpySerializer
from sagemaker.deserializers import NumpyDeserializer

predictor.serializer = NumpySerializer()
predictor.deserializer = NumpyDeserializer()

pred = predictor.predict(data=DataSets[0]['x_test'], target_model="triage.tar.gz")
```

> > > 

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_8216/2859806012.py in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #pred = predictor.predict(data=DataSets[0]['x_test'], target_model="triage.tar.gz")
----> 2 pred = predictor.predict(data=df, target_model="triage.tar.gz")

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id)
    159             data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id
    160         )
--> 161         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    162         return self._handle_response(response)
    163 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528                 )
    529             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    531 
    532         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    958             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    959             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 960             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    961         else:
    962             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from primary with message "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'". See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/mme-incident-triage-2023-05-17-01-49-21 in account 457933018994 for more information.
```

my script is supposed to send it's result as a numpy array, so I made the assumption that I needed to use the numpy deserializer to access the data. maybe by saying that I am demonstarting that I do not know how the serializers work, and if that's the case please tell me what I need to do to fix this. here is my training script as well:

```
%%writefile script/script2.py
import argparse
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

import pickle

def parse_args():
    """
    Parse arguments.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # hyperparameters sent by the client are passed as command-line arguments to the script
    # We don't use these but I left them in as a useful template for future development
    parser.add_argument("--copy_X",        type=bool, default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--fit_intercept", type=bool, default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--normalize",     type=bool, default=False)
    
    # data directories
    parser.add_argument("--train", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN"))
    parser.add_argument("--test", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_CHANNEL_TEST"))

    # model directory: we will use the default set by SageMaker, /opt/ml/model
    parser.add_argument("--model_dir", type=str, default=os.environ.get("SM_MODEL_DIR"))

    return parser.parse_known_args()

def load_dataset(path):
    """
    Load entire dataset.
    """
    # Find all files with a pickle ext but we only load the first one in this sample:
    files = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith("pickle")]

    if len(files) == 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid # of files in dir: {}".format(path))
    
    [X, y] = pickle.load(open(files[0], 'rb'))
    
    return X, y

def start(args):
    """
    Train a Logistic Regression
    """
    print("Training mode")

    try:
        X_train, y_train = load_dataset(args.train)
        # X_test, y_test = load_dataset(args.test)

        print("Training...")
        
        model = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
                       ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                       ( 'clf', LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000))
                        ])
        #model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
        #model.set_params(**hyperparameters)
                
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)

        pickle.dump(model, open(os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.pickle"), 'wb'))
       

    except Exception as e:
        # Write out an error file. This will be returned as the failureReason in the
        # DescribeTrainingJob result.
        trc = traceback.format_exc()
        with open(os.path.join(output_path, "failure"), "w") as s:
            s.write("Exception during training: " + str(e) + "\\n" + trc)

        # Printing this causes the exception to be in the training job logs, as well.
        print("Exception during training: " + str(e) + "\\n" + trc, file=sys.stderr)

        # A non-zero exit code causes the training job to be marked as Failed.
        sys.exit(255)
        
def model_fn(model_dir):
    """
    Load the model for inference
    """
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(model_dir + "/model.pickle", 'rb'))
    return loaded_model


def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    """
    Apply model to the incoming request
    """
    print("helloworld!")
    a = model.predict(input_data)
    b = model.predict_proba(input_data)
    
    # create dictionary
    d = dict(enumerate(model.classes_))
    inv_d = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
    
    # map confidence score
    i = 0
    conf = a.copy()# create numpy array of equal size and dimensions as a, overwrite copied data
    for x in conf:
        conf[i] = b[i][inv_d[x]]
        i = i + 1
    
    c = np.concatenate([a,conf])

    return c



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    args, _ = parse_args()

    start(args)
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace in CloudWatch? Also are you using the same container version for hosting that you used for training.